# Text file in VBA: Open/Find Replace/SaveAs/Close File

Tags: vba, text-files

Here is pseudocode for what I am hoping to do:

```
Open text File

Find "XXXXX" and Replace with "YYYY"

Save text File As

Close text file
```

This is what I have so far

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As String

' Edit as needed
sFileName = "C:\filelocation"

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "DIM A", "1.75")
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "DIM B", "2.00")
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "DIM C", "3.00")
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "DIM D", "4.00")

'Save txt file as (if possible)

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum

Print #iFileNum, sTemp

Close iFileNum

'Close Userform
Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

But instead of overwriting the original text file, I want to "save as" to a new file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add this line

```
sFileName = "C:\someotherfilelocation"
```

right before this line

```
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
```

The idea is to open and write to a *different* file than the one you read earlier (`C:\filelocation`).

If you want to get fancy and show a real "Save As" dialog box, you could do this instead:

```
sFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()
```

Answer (score 19):

Guess I'm too late...

Came across the same problem today; here is my solution using `FileSystemObject`:

```
Dim objFSO
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objTS 'define a TextStream object
Dim strContents As String
Dim fileSpec As String

fileSpec = "C:\Temp\test.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForReading)
strContents = objTS.ReadAll
strContents = Replace(strContents, "XXXXX", "YYYY")
objTS.Close

Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileSpec, ForWriting)
objTS.Write strContents
objTS.Close
```

Comment: Nice and probably faster than the other proposals

Comment: Best of my Choice.

Answer (score 14):

Why involve Notepad?

```
Sub ReplaceStringInFile()

Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As String

' Edit as needed
sFileName = "C:\Temp\test.txt"

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "THIS", "THAT")

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sTemp
Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: How is this code any different from the code in the question?!

Comment: Now that the OP has copy/pasted it into the *edited* version of the original question ... not at all.  ;-)  Thanks for adding the Save As (to different filename) fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and came acrosse this site.

the solution to just set another "filename" in the

... **for output as** ... command was very simple and useful.

in addition (beyond the Application.GetSaveAsFilename() Dialog)

it is very simple to set a** new filename** 
just using

the **replace** command,
so you may change the filename/extension

eg. (as from the first post)

```
sFileName = "C:\filelocation"
iFileNum = FreeFile

Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum
content = (...edit the content) 

Close iFileNum
```

**now just set:**

newFilename = replace(sFilename, ".txt", ".csv")    *to change the extension*

or

newFilename = replace(sFilename, ".", "_edit.")   *for a differrent filename*

and then just as before

```
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open newFileName For Output As iFileNum

Print #iFileNum, content
Close iFileNum
```

I surfed over an hour to find out how to rename a txt-file,

with many different solutions, but it could be sooo easy :)

Answer (score -1):

This code will open and read lines of complete text file
That variable "ReadedData" Holds the text line in memory

```
Open "C:\satheesh\myfile\Hello.txt" For Input As #1

do until EOF(1)   

       Input #1, ReadedData
loop**
```

Comment: This does not address the question.