# VBA search and replace script produce long delays

Tags: vba, ms-word

[[UPDATE: Apologies...I forgot the code block. Edited.]]

This is a question from one of my faculty, so I'll quote him directly, and preface this by saying I don't know VB (just the conduit here):

"In order to help an international student, I need to convert Youtube transcripts and Closed Captionings into readable text.

I wrote this routine for the purpose of eliminating time code marks from Youtube transcripts by invoking Visual Basic from within Microsoft Word. Since time codes are always on a separate line and since time codes must contain “:”, I am searching for the character “:” and then deleting the whole line in which it occurs. For some reason, the routine I have written, when completed, forces Word into a long unresponsive period (around 60-100 seconds) after which it works perfectly well. Any suggestions for avoiding that delay or for solving this problem within Word, without writing macros?"

```
Sub Deleteyt()

Dim oRng As Word.Range

Dim oRngDelete As Word.Range

Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range

With oRng.Find

.Text = ":"

While .Execute

oRng.Select

Set oRngDelete = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Line").Range

oRngDelete.Delete

Wend

End With

End Sub
```

So the code works, there's just the long delay up front. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend sharing your code and a sample document if possible.

Comment: The best you can do is to debug and see exactly where the code stucks, you probably enter a very long unwanted loop. In any case, you should post some code here to have some help.

Comment: Indeed, without code-example this question is useless and not answerable.

Comment: Set Application.ScreenUpdating=False before the start of your search (and back on again afterwards) may help as it will stop word reformatting the document every time you make a deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a macro for this - all you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace, with:

```
Find = <[0-9]@:[0-9]@>*^13
Replace = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not modifying the text file which contains the transcript? I would expect you end up with a .txt file.

See example below, highly insipred from: [Text file in VBA: Open/Find Replace/SaveAs/Close File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434335/text-file-in-vba-open-find-replace-saveas-close-file)

```
Sub CleanFile()

Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As String

' Edit as needed
sFileName = application.GetOpenFilename

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    'If the line does not contain a ':', then include the line in the memory sTemp 
    if If InStr(sBuf, ":") = 0 Then sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

iFileNum = FreeFile

sFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sTemp
Close iFileNum

End Sub
```