# VBA replace file in open document (other than word/excel)

Tags: vba

We use PcSchematic for our electric drawings. And we use PDM to manage the revision. I would like to write into the pcschematic file with the current revision from PDM.

A pcSchematic file can be opened with a notepad. so what I would like to do is:

`Dim filePath as string = "C:\16368.04.PRO"`

1. Open file with notepad `Process.Start("notepad", filePath)`
2. find and replace a line
3. save
4. close

I have tried this:

```
Dim objFSO
Dim objTS
objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, 2)
```

From this [Text file in VBA: Open/Find Replace/SaveAs/Close File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434335/text-file-in-vba-open-find-replace-saveas-close-file)

but it only seems to work for .txt files

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you can open the file with notepad, it's likely a textfile. Note that the syntax you use to define the filename is not valid in VBA - you cannot declare a variable and assing a value to in in the same statement. However, it seems that you don't need a variable anyhow, so change the line to `Const filePath= "C:\16368.04.PRO"`

Comment: About the filepath definition, it was only to save time/space, I have declared it in one line and assigned it a value in another line.